# How pyqt use unittest to check login name and password and result?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pyqt, pyqt5

my error message is

> AttributeError: type object 'MainWindow' has no attribute
>   'nameLineEdit'

i try use pyqt unittest check login name and password (cause my project is pyqt5)

but many unittest are for not gui python project

so i google a tutorial(the tutorial is for pyqt4 but i will need use pyqt5) 
http://johnnado.com/pyqt-qtest-example/

below is my project source code
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gxVzY2yg83_y5OmHYUprsljMoP5xhbLT/view?usp=sharing

and i record my screen 
https://youtu.be/yiMUGphm6fk
about project

my simple pyqt5 project to practice unittest to check login status
i follow a pyqt4 project tutorial ,but not work the project include three scripts

first script(main.py)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
Module implementing MainWindow.
"""
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication

from Ui_main import Ui_MainWindow


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    """
    Class documentation goes here.
    """
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        """
        Constructor

        @param parent reference to the parent widget
        @type QWidget
        """
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_loginButton_clicked(self):
        if self.nameLineEdit.text()=='admin' and self.passwordLineEdit.text()=='123456':
            self.loginStatusLabel.setText('Success Login')
        else:
            self.loginStatusLabel.setText('Failed Login')

if __name__=="__main__":
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    Main=MainWindow()
    Main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

second script (test_login.py)

```
import sys
import unittest
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtTest import QTest

import main

app = QApplication(sys.argv)


class test01(unittest.TestCase):
    '''Test the margarita mixer GUI'''

    def setUp(self):
        print('inital ok')

    def test_defaults(self):

        self.nameLineEdit=main.MainWindow.nameLineEdit
        self.passwordLineEdit=main.MainWindow.passwordLineEdit
        loginButton = main.MainWindow.loginButton

        self.assertEqual(self.nameLineEdit.text(), 'admin')
        self.assertEqual(self.passwordLineEdit.text(), '123456')


        QTest.mouseClick(loginButton, QtCore.Qt.LeftButton)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

third script(Ui_main)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'F:\project\pyqt_unitest01\main.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.10.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(302, 157)
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName("centralWidget")
        self.loginButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralWidget)
        self.loginButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 100, 81, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Agency FB")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.loginButton.setFont(font)
        self.loginButton.setObjectName("loginButton")
        self.nameLineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.nameLineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 10, 181, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Agency FB")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.nameLineEdit.setFont(font)
        self.nameLineEdit.setObjectName("nameLineEdit")
        self.passwordLineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralWidget)
        self.passwordLineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 60, 181, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Agency FB")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.passwordLineEdit.setFont(font)
        self.passwordLineEdit.setObjectName("passwordLineEdit")
        self.nameLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.nameLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 81, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Agency FB")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.nameLabel.setFont(font)
        self.nameLabel.setObjectName("nameLabel")
        self.passwordLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.passwordLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 60, 81, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Agency FB")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.passwordLabel.setFont(font)
        self.passwordLabel.setObjectName("passwordLabel")
        self.loginStatusLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralWidget)
        self.loginStatusLabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 105, 141, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Agency FB")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.loginStatusLabel.setFont(font)
        self.loginStatusLabel.setObjectName("loginStatusLabel")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.loginButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "login"))
        self.nameLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "name"))
        self.passwordLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "password"))
        self.loginStatusLabel.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "login_status"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

how to correct use unittest to test pyqt5 project (or any better idea or framework)
thank you everybody!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that you show is the little knowledge about OOP, the classes are abstractions or molds, they only serve to create objects, and that is what you have not done, so one part of the solution is to create an object of the `MainWindow` class.

On the other hand the testing is done to verify the correct functioning, in your case the verification could not occur in the `QLineEdit`s since for this to have text you must place it, the correct thing is to verify the `loginStatusLabel` since the GUI is the one that has control about it, that is, the user places the username and password, clicks and consequently the indicated label must change.

```
import sys
import unittest
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtTest
from main import MainWindow

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

class test01(unittest.TestCase):
    '''Test the margarita mixer GUI'''
    def setUp(self):
        self.form = MainWindow()

    def test_defaults(self):
        self.form.nameLineEdit.setText('admin')
        self.form.passwordLineEdit.setText('123456')
        QtTest.QTest.mouseClick(self.form.loginButton, QtCore.Qt.LeftButton)
        self.assertEqual(self.form.loginStatusLabel.text(), 'Success Login')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Perfect Replay , Thanks Lot

Comment: By the way I donate 2 USD for you to your reply and help thank you  (not much money just a feedback by me)

Comment: Donation is voluntary, I never ask you, if you give it, thank you, I will have a coffee, otherwise you will continue to help. :)

Comment: if you don't mind , maybe i will get other question in the future on pyqt or python and need your help  ,actually i will payback for your help like this time,anyway thank first